# Hyperlink text on Quip (docs, spreadsheets & tables)

Tags: quip

1. What's the easiest way to add hyperlink to a piece of text on [Quip](https://quip.com/)?
2. Also is there a way to add hyperlink to *only partial text within a cell* (not entire cell contents) of a table in a doc or a Quip spreadsheet?

Answer (score 0):

You can always use the `Link`  button on the toolbar

[image: link button in toolbar]

---

Here are some *faster* tricks

1. Fastest way to hyperlink is to (a) **highlight the piece of text** you want to create hyperlink on and (b) do a **Ctrl + V (Cmd + V on macOS) to paste the URL**
2. For creating hyperlinks on parts of texts within a single cell of a table

   - try the above highlight + paste trick
   - if doesn't work then

     1. first **copy-paste your entire cell contents to a plain quip doc** (not on any sheet or inside table)
     2. **create hyperlink** using above trick
     3. and then **paste back the contents into the original cell**

Comment: How would you do this for formula output? e.g. if part of the link was referenced from another cell?